# Embed XML file in C# assembly - command line

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, command-line

The common method for embedding XML files in a C# executable is to simply add it to the project in Visual Studio, then change its "Build Action" property to "Embedded Resource."

This works very well in Visual Studio, but how can the same result be accomplished with only the command line?

Comment: Would using MSBuild from command line work?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I don't know, I haven't used it. Do you have any more info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the solution was to use the `/res` argument when compiling, with this syntax:

```
/res:MyFile.xml,MyNamespace.MyFile.xml
```

Where `MyFile.xml` is the file in the source directory, and `MyNamepace.MyFile.xml` is the name that's used when calling `GetManifestResourceStream()`.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Is this a parameter while building from MSBuild?

Comment: No, this is a parameter to the C# compiler

Answer (score 2):

MSBuild is more generic tool to build complex project that have more than cople .CS files. MSBuild is command line equivalent of building .CSProj in Visual Studio.

To build solution with MSBuild:

- launch "Visual Studio Command Prompt" (or run command file that sets environment VS variables)
- check if msbuild is correctly in PATH: `msbuild /?"
- specify .Csproj as argument to build it : `msbuild MyProject.csproj`.

Comment: What if `msbuild` isn't available?

Comment: @derekerdmann, Reinstall .Net Framework? (normal location is something like \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe depending on version/bitness)

Comment: No, I mean that I can't use msbuild. It's not that it's missing; it's that the build system doesn't use it (as far as I know).